# Show a div hide another

Tags: jquery, hide, addclass, removeclass

Im sure this topic has been broached before but here goes. My attemp is to hide a div and replace it with its counterpart.. As well, I need to add a class to a item while removing a class from the other. This is pretty simple im sure. Thank you

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.form_sub').hide();
      });
       </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.theader_t').click(function(){
      $('.form_header').show();
      $('.form_sub').hide();
      $('.theader').addClass('active');
      $('sub_theader').removeClass('active');
    });
    </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.sub_theader_t').click(function){
     $('.form_header').hide();
      $('.form_sub').show();
       $('.theader').removeClass('active');
      $('sub_theader').addClass('active');
     });
    </script>
```

My appologies for not asking the question. The first function works, the last 2 dont work at all. I want a.theader_t to show .form_header while adding the class active but taking active from sub_theader_t if it so applies. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks pretty good to me.  I have a couple of comments.  1) you don't have to add a new script tag for every function.  You may have the code in a few different places which is why you included it that way, in which case, that's fine.  2)  I would change your 2 divs to have unique ids instead of the classes you have.  The selector would then be $('#form_header') instead of $('.form_header')

Comment: We are using a CMS program (bleh) that makes us call out to individual scripts.. it oculd be that we dont have to but for now i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the other two functions are not into the

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

and the third function has an error

```
$('.sub_theader_t').click(function){ to 

$('.sub_theader_t').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be ending the script here...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.form_sub').hide();
      });
 </script>
```

The events are not under **Document.Ready**.. Make this modificationa and it should be working fine.. Also make sure to delegate your events once those are available using .on()

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form_sub').hide();

    $('a.theader_t').on('click',function() {
        $('.form_header').show();
        $('.form_sub').hide();
        $('.theader').addClass('active');
        $('.sub_theader').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('.sub_theader_t').on('click' ,function) {
        $('.form_header').hide();
        $('.form_sub').show();
        $('.theader').removeClass('active');
        $('.sub_theader').addClass('active');
    });
< /script>​​​​​
```